# Visas necessary to travel from Moscow to Kalinigrad

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, russia

I'm an Indian planning to visit Baltic countries and Kaliningrad with my wife. I will be traveling from Moscow.

What visas would we need to travel by train?

Comment: I have edited your question to focus on a single question at a time. If you want to ask how to get between Kaliningrad and Mosco as a separate question, that would be better.

Comment: @Flimzy Actually by doing that you changed the question.  Traveling from Moscow to Kaliningrad implies availability of Russian visa but not necessarily the Schengen one.

Comment: @Karlson: I guess I interpreted the question differently.  I thought he was asking what visa he needed to get to Kaliningrad *and* how best to travel between Kaliningrad and Russia.

Comment: @Flimzy The question had both but in this case source point is also important.  Flying from Moscow to Kaliningrad doesn't require an extra visa since flight is domestic but traveling by train does as it crosses Lithuania and, at least it used to, Belarus.  Apparently it still does.

Answer (score 5):

Because you intend to visit the Baltic countries I have to assume that you've already applied and/or received your Schengen visa.  In addition to that you will need to make sure that your Schengen visa is not single entry otherwise you will need to carefully manage your trip.

In addition to the Schengen visa for the Baltic countries on your journey by train from Moscow to Kaliningrad you will need to get a [Belarus Transit Visa (B)](http://www.mfa.gov.by/en/visa/) because the train from [Moscow to Kaliningrad (russian)](http://pass.rzd.ru/timetable/public/ru?STRUCTURE_ID=735&layer_id=5370&refererLayerId=5354&train_num=029CH&numtrain=029%D0%A7&src_code=2000006&departureDate=21.08.2014&firstStation=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB&lastStation=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%20%D0%9F) goes through Belarus before it gets to Lithuania.